# how to retrieve a value in datalist on the button click in DataList

Tags: asp.net, button, datalist, selecteditemtemplate

We have a Datalist in which we have some data, with every Item we have a button control. What I want to achieve is that on the button click, the data related to that particular row of Datalist is fetched whose Button control is clicked. How to accomplish this? The problem is how to attach the button control with values related in that particular row? Note that I am using ArrayList as the Datasource since I am enabling padding via pageDataSource class...

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `OnDataBinding` event for the `Button`.  Then in the `Button` set the `CommandArgument` to something that will identify the row you are clicking.  Then implement the `OnItemCommand` event for the `DataList`.  You will be able to read the `CommandArgument` for the `Button` that was clicked and then perform whatever action you need.